# How to change the width of the header & make it responsive too

Tags: html, flask

I didn't change any code, but the navbar is shortened automatically
If I set `width="300px"` the header becomes unresponsive

Header Code:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url_for('home.home_') }}">
            <img alt="Quizz" height="70" src="../static/logo.png" width="70">
        </a>
        <button aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"
                class="navbar-toggler" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
                data-bs-toggle="collapse" type="button">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <li>
                     <a href="{{ url_for('login_system.logout') }}"><button class="btn btn-success">Log Out</button></a>
                </li>
                {% else: %}
                <li>
                    <a href="{{ url_for('login_system.register') }}"><button class="btn btn-primary">Sign Up!</button></a>
                    <a href="{{ url_for('login_system.login') }}"><button class="btn btn-success">Log In</button></a>
                </li>
                {% endif %}
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Note: This a flask template!

What can I do to make it width to full screen?

Comment: by setting it to pixels you are giving it a fixed with.
1.) You Can control it manually by using media queries.
2.) You Can control it by setting the width to a percentage width.
3.) You Can Control it by using flex-boxes.

Which of the above do you wish to use ?

Comment: Either 1 or 3, Can you give some examples about them

Comment: update your code and add the css part so that i modify it directly

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the meta tag yet? Like `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Comment: Yes, @Trong Vurong

Comment: Try to set `width: 100%;` in order to make width to full sreen.

Comment: Ok, Let me try, Thanks!

Comment: Pleasure! Hope that it can help you

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways one can use media queries but this is how i use mine

// This Styling Applies When The Width Is 500px like on a mobile

```
@media(max-width:500px){ 
// The Width Of The Header Will Be whatEverYouWant When The Screen Width Is 500px
header{
 width:whatEverWidthYouWant
}

}
```

Comment: Will it be responsive?, because that was the problem when I was seeing it on mobile the three lines appear, but the menu items were not inside it was outside the three-line, because even I tried to set the width as described in the question, but it becomes unresponsive

Comment: This is where styling becomes a headache.
You explicitly have to set the specific style in every specified range of pixels.

Back To Your Question.
It will be responsive only for a certain range of screen size and then start messing up when it's it can be responsive no more. That is where you need to check for the size which starts making it unresponsive and then set your media query at the size then start with a different styling all over.

PS: You can have as many media queries in your code as possible